# Classes, and how they relate to one another in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, properties, model

I'm coding in Visual Studio 2017 with C# and trying to wrap my head around Property/Model Classes in a relational manner (I have watched many hours of tutorials/examples!).

I understand I can create a Customer class, with properties such as Name, Currency etc, and another class called Address with phone number, country etc.

What I don't get is how do you create these in a relational manner working with a MS SQL database. E.g. I create a customer "ACME Inc." and one of it's properties is PrimaryAddress which is set to type "Address", so I can link directly to the address's property, however If I need to create the property from data read from a Table I don't understand how to do that. Sure I can do customer1.PrimaryAddress.Country = Canada, or create an address object called Address1 seperatly, but how do I reference an existing Address object using a property of Customer?

Example:

```
    public class Customer
    {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public bool Enabled { get; set; }
            public CAddress PriAddress { get; set } //This points to an object created using the CAddress class below. each customer has only 1 primary address
    }

    public class CAddress
    {
            public int CustomerID { get; set; } //This specifies which Customer this address belongs to
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string MainNum { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm not sure if what I said even makes sense so please let me know if any other information would help. Thanks!

Comment: If a customer can have multiple addresses then the "customer" data and the "address" data would be in two different database tables.  The "address" table would have a foreign key pointing it back to the "customer" table so any given "address" record would belong to a specific "customer" record.

Comment: The relationship between classes and tables in a database is not a "natural" one - they are completely unrelated things. You need an ORM like Entity Framework to map between the two. That is a big subject - Entity Framework is very complex. But it can basically do all the grunt work of reading the data from the tables into the classes and vice versa.

Comment: Hi David,Thanks - Yes my database does have this setup, the tables make sense, but putting it into C# is my problem - how would I store the data using Classes and properties when Addresses belong to a specific customer?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sharper - Yes I understand, I have figured out how to use ADO.NET and am considering using Dapper (as I read and saw evidence of it being much faster than Entity). I can get classes/properties working individually it's just the issue of relating one to the other (e.g. if I run a Select statement loading the entire table Address table in (which includes multiple customers), then load Customers in, how can I reference the already pulled-in Address that belongs to each customer?

Comment: @007bond007 - You don't need reference them, just set property `Customer.PrimaryAddress`to instance of `Address` with correspondent `CustomerId`. How you do it - your own choice. For example: Read customer, read address by customer Id - create customer, create address, set customer.PrimaryAddress. Or With ORM you just need to inform ORM that you want load customer with address and `PrimaryAddress` property will be filled automatically. So property is "reference"

Comment: @Fabio you mean I can do the following for example?

Comment: @007bond007 - Yes, and "pointing" you will do by yourself or ORM will do it if you going to use it

Comment: @Fabio you mean I can do the following for example? Customer1.PrimaryAddress = Address5;? I guess I would just need to be sure to keep track of what Address is what when I convert from MS SQL to Objects. Would you recommend loading only one customer at a time to fill the objects with? I feel if I went and did an a SELECT statement for each customer, then each address, and then went and filled in the primary address and then went to the address and assigned the customer that it would cause lots of overhead

Comment: You can read customers and their address by using `INNER JOIN` then you will do "mapping" from data row to Customer object, where in mapping you will create instance of Address based on row's columns and set it to Customer.PrimaryAddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you talking about is mapping between database objects and classes.
When you loading data from database you simply create instance of expected type with all related properties(other related tables).

```
 SELECT c.Id
    , c.Name
    , a.Id As AddressId
    , a.Street As AddressStreet
 FROM Customer c
     INNER JOIN Address a ON a.CustomerId = c.Id

var query = "SELECT ...";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    var customers = new List<Customer>();
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            var customer = new Customer
            {
                Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                Name = reader.GetString(1),
                PrimaryAddress = new Address
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(2),
                    Street = reader.GetString(3)
                }
            };

            customers.Add(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can use some ORM framework where your mapping code will be more elegant, and all mapping work will be done by ORM framework.
Entity Framework example which returns all customers with address included

```
using (var dbContext = new CustomerDbContext(connectionString))
{
    return dbContext.Customers.Include(customer => customer.PrimaryAddress).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps a lot. Only thing I need to do is figure out how to apply this with Dapper now, but you answered my question so thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you ask is if you retrieve a list of customers(could be just one customer) and a list of addresses(could be just one address), how you can match each address with each customer, right?

If this is the case, what I would do is to define a common property for these two classes, i.e.: CustomerId, and then, once you have the instance(s), just loop through both collections to assign the correct address to the customer by a common CustomerId.

There is [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) that makes this kind of relationship mapping easier to do.